# parse.com - How to query and get json like array from parse.com using PHP SDK?

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm trying to get orders from parse.com using PHP SDK. I have **Order** class in parse. And **Order** class has items column like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "uXtRcVLQ3V",
      "name": "Coca cola",
      "price": 4,
      "thumbnail": "https://parsefiles.back4app.com/taT6ySwwyza3B2MJucucqWz9pMqBZ00Pd7w7hoZf/e8e8d5ee1e5242a1acd759827df41473_pdp-coca-cola-hfcs-2l.png",
      "category": {
        "id": "cYqrWcCzkt",
        "name": "İçecek"
      },
      "offer": true
    },
    1
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "DWzLluzSpb",
      "name": "Darr",
      "price": 12,
      "thumbnail": "https://parsefiles.back4app.com/taT6ySwwyza3B2MJucucqWz9pMqBZ00Pd7w7hoZf/8d7c0eae7c74d269319fed0a4f4e50e7_bilisim-paylasimlari.jpg",
      "category": {
        "id": "bGVCMX79Y0",
        "name": "Deterjan, Temizlik"
      },
      "offer": true
    },
    1
  ]
]
```

I want to get and echo name, price, thumbnail, category of each items in array using Parse PHP SDK.
The beginning of my PHP code is:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("Order");
$results = $query->find();
```

[image]

Comment: I would appreciate an example for this.

Comment: @KrisRoofe I don't get content from file, I query and get it from parse.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved problem. I used nested foreach loop.

```
$query = new ParseQuery("Order");
$results = $query->find();
foreach($results as $obj) {
   $items = $obj->get("items");
   foreach($items as $prod) {
      echo $prod[1] . " x "  . $prod[0]["name"] . "<br>";
   }
   echo $obj->get("total");
}
```